# R/ggplot2: normalize bar plot on secondary data counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to normalize a barplot of data based on secondary data counts.
For example, starting with the following table in data.frame data:

```
ID   Classification
1    neutral
1    low
2    medium
2    high
2    high
3    neutral
3    neutral
4    medium
4    low
5    medium
```

The resulting barplot would have x-axis bars "neutral", "low", "medium", and "high", with the y-axis heights determined by the count of the classification divided by the count of the unique IDs within the Classification. i.e.:

```
neutral = 3/2
low = 2/2
medium = 3/3
high = 2/1
```

I know that to do just the counts the following works:

```
levels(data$Classification) <- c("neutral", "low", "medium", "high")
qplot(Classification, fill = Classification, data = data, geom = "bar") + guides(fill = FALSE)
```

But I'm at a loss trying to figure out how to normalize the data as I've described.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize" ?

Comment: By "normalize," do you mean that you want to get a probability distribution out of it?

Comment: You should call it something other than "normalize", since it doesn't do either of the two operations that commonly are called "normalization".

Answer (score 0):

If by "normalize" you mean get a probability distribution for:

```
netural
low 
medium
high
```

Then, for each property, you take its value and divide it by the sum of all of the values (one for each property). Based on your example, neutral would become:

```
neutral = neutral/(neutral + low + medium + high)
                  or
neutral = 3/2/(3/2 + 2/2 + 3/3 + 2/1)
```

And like I said, you would do this for the three other labels, too, to give you appx:

```
neutral = .273
low = .182
medium = .182
high = .363
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your data as a data frame named DF,

```
library(plyr)
u <- ddply(DF, "Classification", summarise, n = length(unique(ID)), frq = length(ID))
mutate(u, ratio = frq/n)
```

There are a number of other ways to do this with any of the basic summarization functions and/or packages.